# How can I convert .db to .xls?

Tags: database, xls

How can I convert .db to xls ? ı don't know what is it's type. Can anyone explain to me step by step?

Comment: A `*.db` file is possibly a Microsoft Access database file, but not guaranteed.

Comment: I try but access doesnt support db file. for axample a  .accdb file is a access db file . thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download TrIDNet, which will analyze the .db file to find out specifically what kind of database it is. It's possible it could be SQLite, MS Access, etc. The interface is similar to below, but you should have some db related results when run on your specific file.

From there, you should be able to determine what software needs to be used to extract the data from the .db file and convert it to an Excel spreadsheet.

[TrIDNet - File Identifier](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html)

[image: TrIDNet]

Comment: there is no matches with my db files in this TrIDNet? Is there another way to do that?

Comment: It's possible they could be proprietary files or maybe just a text file named .db. Have you tried to open the file in a plain text editor?

Comment: Yes ı Tried and ,there are so many strange characters and words.